# Download a file from github.com with its changeset hash

Tags: git, github

Is there a single URL I can download the latest version of a file on github.com along with the changeset hash? I have an application that needs a local copy of the file and I'd like to record a version info with it.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a lot of informations on files and commits using GitHub API, like this : https://api.github.com/repos/torvalds/linux/commits

Or on a single commit like this : https://api.github.com/repos/torvalds/linux/commits/87ef12027b9b1dd0e0b12cf311fbcb19f9d92539

You should be able to find infos you want, for example you can download raw file using "raw_url attribute"

Comment: This is not a single URL.